# How can I open multiple URLs in Sheets using one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-cell-format

I have been frequently using concatenate to combine cells and strings to render URLs in cells. The purpose of these URLs is to open specific pages to review the information on those pages.

I am looking to create a comma separated (or other) list in one cell where I can open all of the links in separate tabs (especially if it can be in a new window).

Is there a way of using something like `target="_blank` to make Sheets open those links? Would it only be possible using the script editor somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Impossible. The content of a cell is rendered as a hyperlink under certain conditions (when it's detected as a hyperlink or pasted in as rich text with a hyperlink, or contains the `hyperlink` formula). In any  of these cases, the entire cell's content will be one link. It will not contain multiple links.

Answer (score 3):

Google sheets now supports multiple hyperlinks in one cell. Select text fragment and press ctrl+K or use hyperlink icon after selecting text.

Comment: Is there a way to add the distinct hyperlinks via formulas?

Answer (score 0):

<s>While cells formatting allow to apply some styling to text parts of the cell content, currently it's not possible to have more than one hyperlink.</s>

A workaround is to use a script, more specifically to use the HTML Service from Google Apps Script to generate HTML from the cell content in a dialog or sidebar.

Comment: do you have an example on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @Steve Since Google now supports multiple hyperlinks in a cell, in the context of this question the workaround is no longer need. Please checkout this question  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/137221/88163