# How to open multiple urls in different new browser tabs from Google Sheets with a single click?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a row with multiple urls on it. I'd like to open each url  in a separate browser tab without having to click on each link. Is this possible in Google Sheets or Google Apps Script?

Comment: @Rubén, please see my answer below. It's possible via Google Apps Script HtmlService (indirectly). What you said in your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29906951/1045881 is technically correct when you said Script itself will not automatically open web pages, but the end effect is possible via the combination of server and client script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to open multiple urls in different new browser tabs:

[image: multiple urls in different browser tabs]

It creates html script to do the job. Be sure the urls each begin with the protocol (e.g., not just 'www') or google will get confused.

The function takes an array of urls. Those can come from anywhere including `getValues()` where you've got multiple urls on a row in a spreadsheet, or anywhere else.

```
function openTabs(urls) {
  if(!Array.isArray(urls))
    urls = [urls];

  var html = 
    "<script>" + 
      urls.map(function(url) {
        return "window.open('" + url + "');";
      })
      .join('') +
      "google.script.host.close();" + 
    "</script>"; 

  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  .setWidth( 90 )
  .setHeight( 1 );

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Opening...');
}

function testOpenTabs() {
  var urls = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.stackoverflow.com','http://www.wikipedia.com'];
  openTabs(urls);
}
```

Comment: I tested your code. It works! P.S. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @Rubén, gosh thanks Ruben! That's very nice of you :)