# Open multiple urls in different new browser tabs

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

My question is about the previous answer here:

[How to open multiple urls in different new browser tabs from Google Sheets with a single click?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/137683/219739)

I just tried copying and pasting the code and running the functions in Apps Script but it doesn't open the Urls in new tabs.

When I run the `TestOpenTabs()` function nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Does this solution still work?

Answer (score 1):

It does work like a charm!

@TheMaster point showed what was missing:
[Google Apps Script to open a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54675103)

It didn't open the new Tabs simply because my Chrome pop-ups blocker was enabled!

Got it fixed by:

Chrome setting > Pop-ups and redirects  > Allowed