# Add multiple hyperlinks in one cell, using a Formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

in Google Sheets, I am trying to add multiple URLs in one cell, using the Hyperlink Formula.When trying `=HYPERLINK("foo.com","Foo") & " some other text " & HYPERLINK("bar.com","Bar")`, the result is = **Foo some other text Bar** , without the URL links. If I use the "Insert Link" functionality, I am able to add two URls. Is there a way to use the Hyperlink Formula to add multiple URLs in one cell?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. I think that the only alternative is to use Google Apps Script as it has [setlinkurl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder#setlinkurllinkurl)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value

Related

- [How can I open multiple URLs in Sheets using one cell?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109053/88163)

Comment: though Google sheets now supports multiple hyperlinks in one cell. So if it's possible using the "Insert Link" functionality, does it mean that I cannot use a formula for it?

Comment: @SamToufaili you should mark Rubén's reply as answer, it's is 100% accurate, you can't do what you want using a formula and the only way to achieve something similar is with a Google Apps script